# Select Powerpoint slides based on the slide tags and copy into a new presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a slide deck of about 30 slides which is mix of slides for different areas (Azure, AWS etc.). My goal is to be able to pull out specific slides into a new presentation based on requirement. For example pull out all slides related to Azure. So, for this i have assigned tags to each slide (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slide.tags). Now i need help in using these tags to pull out those slides from the main PowerPoint deck into a new PowerPoint deck.

**Code to assign tags:**

```
Sub Assign_tags()
ActivePresentation.Slides(7).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(8).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(9).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(10).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(11).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(12).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(13).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(14).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(15).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(16).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(17).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(18).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(19).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(20).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(21).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(22).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(23).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(24).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(25).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(26).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"

ActivePresentation.Slides(27).Tags.Add "pname", "AWS"

ActivePresentation.Slides(28).Tags.Add "pname", "GCP"
End Sub
```

**Code to copy the slides with Azure tag to a new presentation**

```
    Sub SaveSeparateSlide2()

    Dim curPres As Presentation
    Set curPres = ActivePresentation
    Dim newPres As Presentation
    Set newPres = Presentations.Add

For Each s In curPres.Slides

    If s.Tags("pname") = "Azure" Then

      s.Copy
      newPres.Slides.Paste

    End If

Next

    'change your path and name here:
    newPres.SaveAs "Azure slides.pptx"
    newPres.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: OK, but where is the code you need help with?

Comment: I don't really how to start on this. Up till now i have been able to assign the tags to the slides. I want to next loop through those slides and then select those slides that match the criteria and eventually copy those slides to a new presentation.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using a `For Loop` to assign tags instead of having multiple lines of codes of the same:

```
For i = 7 To 26
ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
Next i
```

Now, we need to pick out the slides which contain the Tag `pname` with the value `azure`

```
    Dim slNum() As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
'above are global declarations

    n = -1 'do this in some initialise sub-routine

Sub SelectSlides()
    For Each s In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
    With s.Tags
        For i = 1 To .Count
          If .Value(i) = "Azure" Then
          n = n + 1
          ReDim Preserve slNum(n)
          slNum(n) = .Parent.SlideIndex 'We now stored the slide number of the slide which contains the tag 
          End If
        Next i
    End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Instead of duplicating the slide you can also copy and paste that slide in the required index.

```
Sub copy()
    ActivePresentation.Slides(i).Copy
    ActivePresentation.Slides.Paste Index:=5
End Sub
```

If you want to move the slide:

```
Sub move()
    ActivePresentation.Slides(3).MoveTo ToPos:=1
End Sub
```

Hopefully, this helps you out!

EDIT: To take the selected slides into a new presentation:

```
Dim pptApp As Object
Dim pptPS As Object

Set pptApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
Set pptPS = pptApp.Presentations.Add

pptPS.SaveAs "Type folder path here"

For i = 0 To n
ActivePresentation.Slides.Item(i).Copy
pptPS.Item(1).Slides.Paste
Next i

pptPS.Save
pptPS.Close
pptApp.Quit

Set pptPS = Nothing
Set pptApp = Nothing
```

I haven't tested the above code, I do not think it will work as it is though (a gut feeling). Please de-bug it.

Comment: Thank you Bhavesh. The for loop is a useful suggestion. I will implement that. However, i am not sure about your suggestion to duplicate slides. All i need is the slides which had the "Azure" tag need to be pulled out and maintain into a new PowerPoint of only those "Azure" tagged slides. It would be great if you can help. I will be trying from my end till then.

Comment: Bhavesh - I have added the code in the initial question that i have created but it is currently not working.

Comment: Added a new code in my answer too! You can also contact me directly in my emails if you need any more assistance.

Comment: I have been able to figure it out and have added my working code below. Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit


Sub Assign_tags()
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(2).Tags.Add "pname", "AWS"
ActivePresentation.Slides(3).Tags.Add "pname", "Azure"
ActivePresentation.Slides(4).Tags.Add "pname", "GCP"
End Sub

Sub extract_slides()

Dim strTagName As String
Dim strTagValue As String

strTagName = "pname"
strTagValue = "Azure"

Dim currentPresentation As Presentation
Dim newPresentation As Presentation
Dim s As Slide

' Save reference to current presentation
Set currentPresentation = Application.ActivePresentation

' Save reference to current slide
'Set currentSlide = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide

' Add new Presentation and save to a reference
Set newPresentation = Application.Presentations.Add

For Each s In currentPresentation.Slides
    If s.Tags(strTagName) = "Azure" Then
         s.Copy
         ' Paste it in new Presentation
        newPresentation.Slides.Paste
    End If
Next

newPresentation.SaveAs (currentPresentation.Path & "\" & strTagValue & "_Extract.pptx")

End Sub
```